# which API support setZOrderOnTop?

Tags: android, android-videoview

i need to invisible black page that shown before play `videoview`, and i used `videoview.setZOrderOnTop(true)`..... so in run my app in some different devices to test it but i found that a device with android 2.3.3 couldn't make that black screen invisible with `setZOrderOnTop`.... where is the problem ? the android version or the device?

if android 2.3.3 doesn't support `setZOrderOnTop`, what is solution to make that black screen invisible in android 2.3.3 ?

Comment: Have you read the Android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)?

Comment: yes but anywhere talk about API level

Comment: On the web page I posted, you should have seen this text **Added in API level 1** written in bold. Please read the URL link again.

Comment: @ChuongPham I believe this was **Added in API level 5** if you look at the `SurfaceView` docs.

Comment: yes u r right , thank u so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(boolean)` was added in [API 5 (Android 2.0)](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.0.html).

You can always check for API level compatibility by looking at the Android docs. In your case, the `VideoView` extends `SurfaceView`. The method you are interested in comes from the `SurfaceView` class, so look at the docs here:

- [SurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(boolean) on Android Developers guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean))

---

If the goal is to hide the video preview window, I know that one workaround used is to make the view really small (1x1) and place it in a corner of the screen.

That way the system still has a view to preview onto, but the user does not have to see the video stream.

This is often used by "Flashlight" apps that require a video preview window before being able to turn the LED on.

Comment: Isn't the question talking about why this method doesn't work as expected on `API 10`?

Comment: Yes, but the title asks "which API supports..." - @Vikram pls post if you know of an API 10 problem with the method, you'll get my upvote for sure.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Ahhh, okay. Sorry, got confused after reading the question body. You have my vote.

Comment: @Vikram I hoped you had more info on [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/yaLEszDg_Eo/pDGQiF5kiUAJ) which suggest there is a bug in Gingerbread and HoneyComb. Although Dianne Hackborn makes a good case for there not being a bug, since this method is used in the stock launcher on those versions.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I was just going through the same link. Dianne also mentions: `... be sure you are setting this property before the SurfaceView is attached to its window, and never changing it.` But I doubt this is the issue. @KOMET would not have had success on other API/devices if they weren't setting this property as intended.

Comment: @Vikram I particularly enjoy the part where she says `...it is too bad we made that API public.`

Comment: :/ what can i do ?! it really bad ! my app works like Swiss made watches on android 4 and up ! but in lower android its like a silly amateur made app :'(  .the solution they told is general and didn't work on my case !